# can I use `=` sign operator with sub-query instead of `IN`

Tags: oracle

I am just wondering if use `=` sign operator with sub-query instead of `IN` 
Is it correct way ? and meet the oracle standard ?

**Example**

```
select column_name from my_table_1 where id = (select max(id) from my_table_2);
```

Comment: It is ok to use '='  for sub-queries returning a single row (in your case), but fails when it returns multiple rows.

Comment: `=` is even the preferred way here, because the subquery retrieves exactly one row. Use `=` instead of `IN` everytime you know the subquery will return only one or zero rows.

Comment: This is nothing Oracle specific by the way, but standard SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The Difference is related to the number of rows returned. If you have only one row returned from nested sql you may prefer both `=` or `in` operators. But if multiple rows returned from nested query, use `in` operator.

So, in your sql example you may prefer using any of the operators. Since, `max` functions returns only one row.

Answer (score 0):

As you are fetching maximum value from subquery to compare with id, Both(= and IN )will work fine. But If you are trying to fetch more than one row then you have to use IN keyword.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 1 result in sub query you are fine with using `=` sign, except when data type is wrong, for example , checking with same data type of dummy `VARCHAR2(1)`

```
select * from dual where 'X' = (select max(dual.dummy) from dual);
```

Is similar to using `in` (also same explain plain)

```
select * from dual where 'X' in (select max(dual.dummy) from dual);
```

But checking with different/wrong data type will result with exception `ORA-01722 Invalid number`

```
select * from dual where 1 =(select max(dual.dummy) from dual);
```